# Bluemix Mobile Application Security - User Authentication

Tags: security, authentication, ibm-cloud

In the Bluemix documentation, 2 options are available for the User Authentication in Mobile Application Security (MAS) :

1. Google Sign-in
2. Worklight Sign-in

The documentation talks about the security token, how MAS can validate the security token and obtain user information.

In the case I would like to use Worklight sign-in, does it mean that the mobile application needs first to authenticate with a Worklight Server, which will create a LTPA token for the session, and Bluemix is able to validate this LTPA token and obtain the user information ?

In that case, the mobile needs to talk first to the Worklight server before it can talk to Bluemix. But the Worklight server is on-premise, so behind the Cloud Integration in Bluemix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your mobile app will need to validate with your on-premise Worklight server and get an auth token before talking to Bluemix. First, you will need to implement code to acquire the security token from the Worklight server. Then you will be able to set the token with the provided SDK to be passed in the headers on all HTTP requests to Mobile Cloud services.

In order for MAS to validate the token, you will need upload the contents of the public key file from your Worklight server into the MAS dashboard.

You can find more in depth details for this process [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mas/index.html#userauthentication).